# Arduino void function declaration

Tags: c++, arduino

HI there I have an error:

```
deska0_1:263: error: no match for call to '(String) (bool)'

   koloron ( 1 );

deska0_1:265: error: no match for call to '(String) (bool)'

   koloroff ( 1 );

exit status 1
no match for call to '(String) (bool)'
```

in void function:

```
    void blinkall (String kolor, int pauza)
{
  String koloron;// declaring new string
  String koloroff;

  koloron = String ( kolor + "n" ); 
  koloroff = String ( kolor + "f" );

  koloron ( 1 );
  delay (pauza);
  koloroff ( 1 );
  delay (pauza);
}
```

problem is i'm not calling koloron or koloroff as arguments of blinkall
what I want is:
function blinkall take 2 arguments:
kolor which is color 
pauza which is blink delay

earlier in a code there's another void called for example redn ( turns on red led ) and another redf ( which turns it off)

so now as argument of function blinkall what I want is:

Blink all take 2 arguments color and delay
example

blinkall (red, 100)
I want it to run
red + n == redn // this is another void function to turn led on
and then delay
and then red + f == redf // also another void to turn off

I hope i've made it clear enough :)

Comment: `koloron` and `koloroff`  are `strings` and you used it as functions.

Comment: C++ doesn't work that way. C++ isn't an interpreted language. I am pretty sure, that there is a better way of doing whatever you are actually tying to do.

Comment: I'm actually doing that on arduino but I guess function declaration is the same at both?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for errors in the wrong place. The problem in not in the function arguments. The compilation error says explicitly that the problems are with
`koloron ( 1 )` and `koloroff ( 1 )`. `koloron` and `koloroff` are strings and you're trying to assing integers to them (in this case `1` is interpreted as `true` by the compiler, so `bool`, hence the error message). Try

```
koloron = "1";
koloroff = "1";
```

Comment: Thing is I want this string to call another function with argumengs

Comment: @MichałS are you saying that you have, for instance, functions called for instance bluen, bluef, redn, redf... and you want to pass "blue" and get the bluen/bluef functions, then pass "red" and get redn and redf...? If so, sorry, but the C language does not allow you to do that runtime. You will have to change your code. Best solution is to have an enumeration with the colors and then either perform a switch on it or, better, if the only thing which differs from one color to the other is just the pin avoid duplicating the function code and pass the pin as parameter.

Comment: Ok you have an idea but I'm using 5 analog led's and koloron ( 1 ) parameter was a led number 12345... with pin numbers assigned in different function, so If I call redn ( 1&&4). I want 1st ant 4th led to light. Isn't there any option to call a function from string or char array?

Comment: Maybe i'm just trying to make simple thing too complicated because it all goes only about blinking some leds but...